# Route Exported NextJs doesn't connect to non index pages

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, routes, next.js

I'm hosting an exported NextJs site on DreamHost. The problem is that I can't link directly to subpages (ex. [www.url.com/about](http://www.url.com/about)) unless they are HTML files ([www.url.com/about.html](http://www.url.com/about.html)).

I have a manual fix which is copying the file into a folder of its own name and renaming it index.html, but that will be problematic eventually, and I don't want to have to do this every update.

I also tried adding a `.htaccess` file, but it doesn't seem to be working. Since I'm not used to working with these files it is possible I'm doing something wrong.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

What should I do? Is there a simple way to route the HTML files to the conventional routes on initial entry?

Comment: Hey Quinn, did you ever come up with a solution? I'm having the same exact problem.

Comment: My temporary/permanent solution was to create a folder with the route name and place the generated file in that folder renamed to index.

ex.
about.html
/about
--- index.html

Comment: That's what I did too. It seems Next.js can do it for you, but at the cost of adding trailing slashes to all your URLs https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash

Comment: Thats not too bad, I think I'll start using that. Thanks.